# Getting Youtube and Gmail to work under two different accounts

Tags: gmail, youtube, account-management

I swear that I was able to sign into a separate Youtube account (x@mycustom.com) and Gmail (p@gmail.com) yesterday. I know this because I constantly check gmail and youtube (where I never really sign out/ never really remember signing out).

Because of the service changes months back with the whole

- Cannot change username
- Cannot unlink accounts

I thought my solution by signing with my custom (i.e. university) address would solve the trick and it for a while. Now today I cannot get back this trick.

This question is not about linking. This question is about getting a youtube account (I know I could do this with youtube account pre google acquisition) and a gmail session running at the same time under different usernames.

Solutions I am not looking for

- Use two different browsers / windows
- Just don't sign into youtube (I have subscriptions that I follow closely)

Comment: Hopefully the enable multi-sign on for youtube, which should resolve this issue, or at least make it a lot easier to switch between the two accounts.

Comment: At least for me. I do not think I can use multi sign with youtube. Its not listed. Its nice for having two gmail accounts though.

Comment: One can use 2 different Google accounts for Google and Youtube simultaneously, in Vivaldi and Firefox (tested latest versions), but it does not seem to work in Chrome. See my answer [***here***](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48039/how-to-login-to-youtube-and-gmail-separately/101043).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has enabled multiple sign-in with the use of [Switch Account](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/08/google-multiple-sign-in-now-available.html). YouTube also supports this ability to switch between accounts.

For Gmail

1. Login to Gmail
2. Click your full name or email address in the Google bar.
3. From the dropdown menu, click Switch account or Sign in to another account...

For YouTube

1. Click your username in the upper right hand side of the page
2. From the dropdown menu, above sign out, click Switch account.

Once you're logged in to both accounts, you'll be able to go back and forth between them without having to log out and log back in with different accounts.

Comment: Google documentation seems to be outdated on this https://accounts.google.com/b/0/MultipleSessions as YouTube is not listed. Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to use the stealth mode of your browser of choice (E.g. Internet Explorer's InPrivate or Chrome's Incognito mode). That way one stealth window can access one service with one account while the other uses the second service with the second account.

PS: This would work even with the two windows accessing the same service, i.e. you can be logged into two gmail accounts at the same time.

Comment: I like it. At least it solves one of the other problems I have had with two gmail accounts. I wish this could work as a tab.

Answer (score 3):

If you use firefox, you can also install the ProfileSwitcher ( [1](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/profileswitcher-en.html) ) add-on for firefox.

It allows my wife and I to use our two different FireFox user profiles at the same time, without the need for the current user of the PC to log off. And you can have more than two profiles!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this:

1. Logout of every Google service you have
2. Log into YouTube with the desired service
3. Log into Gmail with the new service.

I use it this way as my Gmail service (custom domain setup) doesn't allow me to use YouTube.