# Google Accounts Management : YouTube email migration

Tags: gmail, google, youtube

Ok, I have two google accounts / mail accounts.

One I've been using for years and has almost a GB of mails and lots of stuff connected to it. The second one I just created but has a more desirable mail address.

I want to connect YouTube to the second account, easy right?

Well, no. My YouTube account is associated with my old Google account (**oldie** from now on), so there's no way to connect it to the new account (**newbie** from now on).

This brings a boatfull of awkward problems. For instance, I tried activating multi-sign in from Google Accounts, that's fine, I can see both gmail accounts, but if **oldie** is not loaded as the default account, I can't log into YouTube without disconnecting **newbie**. I can't seem to change this either. No matter how hard I try, I can't accomplish having **newbie** as the default account, and being logged into YouTube and **oldie**.

Anyone has come through this weird situation where you can disassociate a YouTube account from a Google Account? The only "option" that I have would be to delete **oldie** permanently, but that's not even close to being a real answer, since I used that mail address for years and I have far more services hooked up to it than just YouTube (feedburner, gTalk, blogger, calendar, social networks, etc).

I'd love a solution for this, or at least a reasonable explanation as to why this is happening. I feel so lonely here.

Update: pics

[image: Email Options]

[image: Manage Account]

The weird thing is, I'm not even sure a Google Account can have a primary email address other than a gmail address...

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7179/getting-youtube-and-gmail-to-work-under-two-different-accounts

Comment: Doesn't really help me, I use firefox, and that plugin wants me to open multiple windows, that's awful, I'd rather have my google problem than open two firefox windows

Comment: Then you are out of luck...those are your options. That youtube account is permanently locked. Deleting the youtube user results in no recovery of that account.

Comment: One can use 2 different Google accounts for Google and Youtube simultaneously, in Vivaldi and Firefox (tested latest versions), but it does not seem to work in Chrome. See my answer [***here***](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48039/how-to-login-to-youtube-and-gmail-separately/101043).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unlink your old Google account from your YouTube account. In YouTube, under Account Settings->Manage Account, there should be an [option](http://www.youtube.com/account#manage/unlink) "Unlink YouTube and Google Accounts." Once you unlink them, you should be able to link your new account with your YouTube account and multiple sign in will play nice.

YouTube accounts created after YouTube joined Google are considered part of your overall Google account. There is no real way of separating them (you couldn't separate your Gmail account from the rest of your account, per se). I have the option to unlink because I created my account before that, and Google sees my YouTube account as an account that just happens to be associated with a Google account.

Comment: Except I can't see that option. I get: "Your Google Account's primary email address is a Gmail address, and thus can't currently be changed."

Comment: @Nico When did you set up your youtube account?

Comment: Joined: January 04, 2010

Comment: @Nico See my updated answer