# How to login to YouTube and Gmail separately?

Tags: gmail, youtube, account-management, google-account

I have an account `address1@gmail.com` which I used to make a YouTube account years ago (before Google bought YouTube).  It got banned for some stupid reason so I made another YouTube account with `address2@gmail.com` and all was good.

`address1@gmail.com` is my main e-mail account that I use for everything.  However, when I go to YouTube, I am "Logged out" because `address1@gmail.com` is banned.  When I click on "Sign In", my only option is to "Sign out and log in with another account".

A workaround I found was to log in with `address2@gmail.com` and Add Account with `address1@gmail.com`, which works except now `address2@gmail.com` is my default account.  So whenever I search, go to Gmail, Maps, etc. it will all be logged as `address2@gmail.com`.

Are there any other suggestions as to what I can do?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid suggestion, but have you tried asking them to remove the ban?

Comment: @johnny I am pleased to announce that the ban was magically lifted with the new Youtube update.  Probably has something to do with the Google+ integration.

Answer (score 4):

The Chrome browser allows you to have separate "users" now. Go to "Users" > "Add New User". Each user has different extensions, logs into chrome with a different email address, and best of all it saves which tabs and active logins each user has open. So you'll have two separate browser windows but this should definitely solve the problem. Just don't accidentally go to YouTube on user 1!

Answer (score 2):

Google has enabled multiple sign-in with the use of [Switch](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/08/google-multiple-sign-in-now-available.html). YouTube also supports this ability to switch between accounts.

For Gmail

1. Login to Gmail
2. Click your full name or email address in the Google bar.
3. From the dropdown menu, click Switch account or Sign in to another account...

For YouTube

1. Click your username in the upper right hand side of the page
2. From the dropdown menu, above sign out, click Switch account.

Once you're logged in to both accounts, you'll be able to go back and forth between them without having to log out and log back in with different accounts.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't because my first account is banned from years ago.

Comment: it means youtube account?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Chrome's [Incognito Mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464).

Comment: Can you give a bit more details about how/why this should work to answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use two separate browsers.

Bring up Gmail in your favorite browser:Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari.

Then bring up YouTube in your 2nd favorite browser.

I used to use this trick when I personal Gmail, and my company had Google Apps. I didn't want to get them confused.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is: a way to log into youtube with account X and in all others services with account Y. Unfortunately, you can't do that in a single browser profile. But you can solve this problem by creating another browser profile.

In Chrome, go to settings > User profiles. Click add profile to create another profile. Now log into it with a diff account. Bingo, now you can use two or three or 346236955... Google accounts on a single browser.

Comment: For Vivaldi and Firefox a wonderful solution exists (see my answer), Chrome though seems to enforce one account policy.

Answer (score 0):

One can use 2 different Google accounts for Google and Youtube simultaneously, in Vivaldi and Firefox (tested latest versions), but it does not seem to work in Chrome. The very incredibly simple way to accomplish this is described below:

1. Log out of both Gmail and YouTube.
2. Open a browser tab with the Gmail login page.
3. Open a browser tab with the YouTube login page.
4. Fill in your user credentials in each login page, but DO NOT log in
   yet. Make sure the text cursor is in the password field on both
   login pages.
5. Switch to the YouTube login page and press Enter to log in.
6. Quickly switch to the Gmail login page and press Enter to log in.

Note: Experiment which first to login, Google or Youtube. The correct order *changes*.

[ All credit goes to [Brother Lobster](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/_8VqfRz00Dc) from a Google forum thread ]

Answer (score 0):

The nice approach described by **Steelsouls** for Chrome is also accessible in Firefox, through a Add-on named "Firefox Multi-Account Containers".

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/