# YouTube account switching issues

Tags: gmail, google-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Youtube and Gmail to work under two different accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7179/getting-youtube-and-gmail-to-work-under-two-different-accounts)

I have two Gmail accounts, one provided by my university, the other personal. The school one does not support YouTube, the personal one does.

I have enabled account switching to log into both at the same time.

No matter what order I do it in, if I am logged into the school account in addition to my personal one, YouTube will tell me that my school account does not support YouTube, I have to log out of that etc.

How can this be "streamlined"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Log out of all your accounts, log into YouTube using your personal Gmail account and then log in using your school account.