# Gmail - Youtube linked

Tags: gmail, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Youtube and Gmail to work under two different accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7179/getting-youtube-and-gmail-to-work-under-two-different-accounts)

Okey, first of all, English is not my native language, so I apologize for my mistakes.
Now, i have 2 gmail accounts, one just for fun, friends and stuff and the other for work, but sometimes i'm in youtube watching some video, maybe releated to my work and then i want to login in gmail to send the link to some friends, with my personal gmail account, but the sistem for default open the same account I'm using on Youtube.
So, so basically, I wish I could be logged with an account on Youtube, and then if a want to use Gmail just get the loging page again to choose witch account i want to use for the email, and by doing this, not logged out from youtube, can i do that ?